# Kafka Streams application integrate with Kafka JDBC sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use kafka streams for some sort of computation, and send the result of computation to a topic which is sinked to database by JDBC sink connector. The result needs to be serialized using avro with confluent schema registry. Is there any demo or guide to show how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean by "integrate"; Kafka Streams is independent from Kafka Connect, however both can be used from ksqlDB

The existing examples of Kafka Connect should be adequate enough using the output topic of your Streams tasks

As for Kafka Streams, you'd need to use the Confluent Avro Serde's and add Schema Registry URL to the StreamsConfig.

Comment: "integrate" here means that output message of kstream as input of kafka sink. But it seems there isn't any complete demo for this scenario. Can you provide a url for the demo project?

Comment: Asking for off site resources is off topic for Stackoverflow. Search the Confluent github repos / blogs. Again, Kstreams is separate from Kafka Connect. It is only used between Kafka topics, not from other systems like a database. What you're asking for is what a sink already does - it consumes a topic